# MySQL trigger communication between two tables

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-workbench

The problem is: I'm trying to find a value from one table where their vaccine choice is 'Janssen', I want the trigger to then copy their patient_id, the result of this will update the patient table and set the vaccination status to 'fully vaccinated' where it equals to the copied patient_id.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `database`.`patient_BEFORE_INSERT_1` BEFORE INSERT ON `appointment` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF NEW.vaccine_Choice = "Janssen" THEN

UPDATE patient
SET new.vaccination_Status = "Fully Vaccinated" 
where patient_id = new.patient_id;
 
END IF;
END
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Not `SET new.vaccination_Status`, `SET patient.vaccination_Status`

I would prefer to create a Stored Procedure that does whatever is needed to both tables, and maybe other tables.